# Material UI Vertical scrolling, column widths

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Has anyone figured out how to get material ui next (v.1+) to vertically scroll with the table header locked at the top. I've gotten to a point where it does scroll but now my column widths don't match. Can someone let me know what I've done wrong? I'm trying to get the width of the table header row cells to match the table body row cells.

Styles

```
const styles = theme => ({
     table: {
        height: "100px",
        borderBottom: "2px solid gray" 
     },
     tableHead: {
        border: "1px solid #d0d0d0",
        height: "25px",
        background: "#f2f2f2",
        display: "block",
     },
     tableHeaderRow: {
        height: "25px",
        width: "100%",
        display: "table",
     },
     tableHeaderCell: {
        border: "1px solid #d0d0d0",
     },
     tableBody: {
        height: "100px", 
        marginTop: "theme.spacing.unit * 3", 
        overflowY: "auto",
        overflowX: "hidden",
        border: "1px solid grey",
        display: "block"
     },
     tableBodyRow: {
        height: "15px",
        borderRight: "2px solid #d0d0d0",
        display: "table",
        width: "100%",
     }

});
```

Table Code

```
<Table className={classes.table}>
          <TableHead className={classes.tableHead}>
            <TableRow className={classes.tableHeaderRow}>
              <TableCell className={classes.tableHeaderCell} key={0}>
                table row 1
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell className={classes.tableHeaderCell} key={1}>
                table row 2
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell className={classes.tableHeaderCell} key={2}>
                table row 3
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody className={classes.tableBody}>
            {data.history
              ? data.history.map((iterator, index) => {
                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      key={index}
                      className={classes.tableBodyRow}
                    >
                      <TableCell style={{ border: "1px solid #d0d0d0" }}>
                        Cell 1
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell style={{ border: "1px solid #d0d0d0" }}>
                        cell2
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell style={{ border: "1px solid #d0d0d0" }}>
                        cell 3
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })
              : null}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
```